# Is the const qualifier in c preserved when casting a const pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

For example would p be pointing to a constant char?

```
const void* a;
char* p = (char*)a;
```

Comment: Nops, `const` is not preserved, and you should get a warning from the compiler at least in pedantic mode.

Comment: In this example p will contain a garbage value pointing to nowhere in particular.

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Neither GCC nor Clang warn with `-Wall` (although Clang does with `-Weverything`), and there is no reason `-pedantic` should change that, as it is a conversion defined by the standard. More than that, casting away `const` is required to use `printf("%p")` properly, as its argument should be `void *`. It is also sometimes needed when a module cast a `T *` to `const T *` when giving it to another module and later receives back the `const T *` that it needs to revert to `T *`. That is a shortcoming in the C language due to historical development, but it is the way it is.

Comment: With `const void* a; char* p = (char*)a;`, The assignment causes `p`to have an indeterminate value or causes a trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider this code first:

```
const char c = 'x';
char *p = (char *) &c;
```

`p` points to `x` and has type `char *`, not `const char *`. However, `x` remains defined with `const`, and the C standard does not define the behavior of attempting to modify `*p`, as by executing `*p = 'y';`.

Next, consider this code:

```
char c = 'x';
const char *p = &c;
char *q = (char *) p;
```

In the third statement, the `const char *p` is converted to a `char *`. This is allowed. Furthermore, `*q = 'y';` is defined by the C standard. What is important is whether the object was originally **defined** with `const`.

You are allowed to explicitly convert pointers to add and remove `const`. However, it is your obligation to know whether the original object was defined with `const`. If it was, the behavior of modifying it is not defined, regardless of any conversions. If it was not, you may modify the object, using a pointer without `const`, regardless of any intervening conversions.

Note that in `const char *p = &c;` no cast is needed. The language allows `const` to be implicitly added. However, it cannot be implicitly removed; you must use an explicit cast when removing `const`.

In the case of your original code:

```
const void* a;
char* p = (char*)a;
```

We do not know what `a` was pointing at. We do know that `p` carries no record of whether it was `const` or not. However, the C implementation may have that information in one form or another, and, if you attempt to use `p` to modify an object that was originally defined with `const`, then the behavior is not defined by the C standard.